# Does coffeescript have an onLoad like event for the browser

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a way to have some code run in the browser after coffeescript has compiled and run all the script files in the header?
Something like:

> coffee.onCompiled () -> console.log "I've finished loading all the coffee files"

How else can I get this behaviour? (please don't suggest setTimeout)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At first I thought you were asking about how to attach a callback to `window.onload` from CoffeeScript (which is, of course, very straightforward, since "It's just JavaScript"), but now I realize that you're asking how you ensure that code runs after all

```
<script type="text/coffeescript" src="..."></script>
```

tags have been executed when using `coffee-script.js`.

One solution is to put a callback in the last CoffeeScript you load. Since 1.1.0, `coffee-script.js` has ensured that all CoffeeScript `script` tags are run in order (though note that they'll only run after all JavaScript `script` tags have run). So, for instance, if you put

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  onReady()
</script>
```

after all your other `script` tags, and define `window.onReady` somewhere else, then that function will be called after all scripts have loaded. If you made it

```
 $ -> onReady()
```

(with jQuery), then you'd ensure that the DOM is ready as well as all scripts.

**Update:** I posted that this is "one solution" because I wasn't 100% sure whether there's a callback that `coffee-script.js` invokes after all scripts have been run. But after checking [the source](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/src/browser.coffee), I can confidently say that it doesn't, so the *only* solution is to put code in the last `<script type="text/coffeescript">` tag. (Whether it's inline or in a `.coffee` file doesn't matter.)