# Adapting a coffeescript to use window.onload

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript, which works except for the fact that when images take a while to load it runs before the images are loaded and then doesn't have the desired effect:

```
ready = ->
  jQuery ->
    $('.box').find('img').each ->
      imgClass = if @width / @height > 1 then 'wide' else 'tall'
      $(this).addClass imgClass
      return
    return


$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

How can I run my function only after the entire window is loaded?

My best attempt so far looks like

```
window.onload = ->
  $('.box').find('img').each ->
    imgClass = if @width / @height > 1 then 'wide' else 'tall'
    $(this).addClass imgClass
    return
  return
```

but it doesn't work. I've tried several other possibilities too but I can't figure out whats wrong.

My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656951/does-coffeescript-have-an-onload-like-event-for-the-browser) since I don't want to wait until all the coffeescripts have finished loading, I want to wait until all of the images in my webpage have loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does coffeescript have an onLoad like event for the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656951/does-coffeescript-have-an-onload-like-event-for-the-browser)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. See my edit which explains why.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To execute your desired code AFTER all images are loaded, use jQuery's `load()` method on the **window**. `document` watches the DOM, while `window` watches the contents.

In coffee, it would look like this:

```
$(window).load ->
  alert 'All images are loaded'
```

The difference between this and what you had is you were using `window.onload` whereas I'm suggesting `$(window).load()`.